# How to improve this javascript code loading JSON files to be more dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm building a web page with a collection of html tables. The data for each table is stored JSON files and I wrote a JQuery method to load the data and render it into HTML.  Currently, this looks like

```
HTML
<!-- Load sample_triangles.json into the following table -->
<table class="table json-triangle" data-filename="data/sample_triangles.json"></table>

<!-- Load sample_triangles2.json into the following table -->
<table class="table json-triangle" data-filename="data/sample_triangles2.json"></table>


JQuery
function renderTriangle(tri){
    //Renders a single triangle object to HTML (assumed to be wrapped inside <table> </table>)
    ...
    return str_tbl;
};

$.getJSON('data/sample_triangles.json', function(data){
  $('table[data-filename="data/sample_triangles.json"]').html(renderTriangle(data['ActiveCustomers']));
});

$.getJSON('data/sample_triangles2.json', function(data){
  $('table[data-filename="data/sample_triangles2.json"]').html(renderTriangle(data['ActiveCustomers']));
});
```

How can I generalize this code better so that simply creating a `<table>` element with a `data-filename` attribute will trigger JQuery to search for a json file with the given filename and attempt to render it in the table?

Comment: If purpose of this question is just to seek improvements in your working code, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the right place for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would go something like this:

```
$("table").each(function(){
  var filename = $(this).data("filename");
  var this1 = $(this);
  $.getJSON(filename,function(data){
    this1.html(renderTriangle(data['ActiveCustomers']));
  });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to work. filename is undefined (but I'm certain it's set in the HTML).  If I change every `$(t)` to `$(this)`, filename gets set correctly but then I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined`

Comment: where did you define the `document.createDocumentFragment`??

Comment: Bingo.  Thanks for the help.